# How can I implement adapter for my list view to show iPhonis contacts list

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

In current I am using section indexer in my contact list view, now I want to update its functionality and to show list view as in iPhone like

[image]

I have no idea about it, and I googled about it also, but didn't get more info.
Can you please help me.

I tried https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge/tree/master/demo and http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/.

Comment: I got the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738679/how-to-make-the-section-header-of-a-separatedlistadapter-push-the-previous-sectio/7739084#7739084

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution.

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/) is a demo application and [source code](http://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/source/checkout).

*Screen Shots of this demo :*

[image]
[image]

*Thanks to developers of this listview demo.*

Enjoy.

---

And [Another API is here.](http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/)

Comment: Thanks - I found the AmazingListView worked pretty well.
https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/

I had issue with StickyListHeaders in 2.3.x https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders