# how to make the section header of a SeparatedListAdapter push the previous section while scrolling?

Tags: android

I am using a SeparatedListAdapter. The Next section's header when reaches the top, the section header changes abruptly. In case of an iOS app, the next section's header pushes up the old section header and takes its position. how to implement that in an android app? any help?

Comment: check this two demo [1](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/pinned-section-listview-by-beworker/) & [2](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/80/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/) is a demo application and [source code](http://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/source/checkout).

*Screen Shots of this demo :*

[image]
[image]

*Thanks to developers of this listview demo.*

Enjoy.

---

And [Another API is here.](http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/)

Comment: How can i clone Project? any Idea?

Comment: You need to install git on your system. Take a look here http://gitref.org/creating/

Comment: this does not push the section headers when a new section header approaches. it just replaces the header. i'm not sure. i did not try. but that is what i guess is how this works...

Comment: @Sudarshan Bhat thanks for your guess. You are very intelligent. But this example pushes the old header with new one, smart guy!

Comment: can you help me get it using git? i have no knowledge of git :(

Comment: BTW, that doesn't seem to be a git repo!!

Comment: it still does not work like the one in iOS. when i said the lower section header pushes the upper section header, i expected little physics! just try some iOS section lists. u ll know.