# How can i add a sticky header to my ListView?

Tags: android, listview, header

I am having a listView, so i want to add a sticky header so that it sticks to the top of the listView and when a different category starts in the listView a Different header take its place, Like the contacts, where is "a" as a Sticky header is at the top till "b" comes in.
Is there any library to do it??
I am using custom List Adapter to show my List...

this is my custom adapter class

```
public class NewsRowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>  {

private Activity activity;
private List<Item> items;
private Item objBean;
private int row;

private DisplayImageOptions options;
ImageLoader imageLoader;

public NewsRowAdapter(Activity act, int resource, List<Item> arrayList) {
    super(act, resource, arrayList);
    this.activity = act;
    this.row = resource;
    this.items = arrayList;



    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    File cacheDir1 = StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(activity);

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new
    ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(activity)
    .maxImageWidthForMemoryCache(600)
    .maxImageHeightForMemoryCache(400)
    .httpConnectTimeout(5000)
    .httpReadTimeout(20000)
    .threadPoolSize(3)
    .threadPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY + 3)
    .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
    .memoryCache(new UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache(20000)) // You can pass your own memory cache implementation
    .discCache(new TotalSizeLimitedDiscCache(cacheDir1, 30000)) // You can pass your own disc cache implementation
    .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple())
    .build();


    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
//              imageLoader = ImageLoader;
//      

   options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showStubImage(R.drawable.icon2x)
    .showImageForEmptyUrl(R.drawable.icon2x).cacheInMemory()
    .cacheOnDisc().build();
//imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

}

@Override
public Item getItem(int position)
{
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount()
{
    return 3;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    Item item = items.get(position);
    if (item.isHeader())
    {
        return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER;
    }
    else
    {
        return TYPE_LIST_ITEM;
    }
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    if ((items == null) || ((position + 1) > items.size()))
        return view;

    objBean = items.get(position);

    holder.tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    holder.tvId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
    holder.tvFlag = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.flag);
    holder.tvimageurl=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageurl);
    holder.tvGender = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    //holder.tvAge = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvage);
    holder.pbar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.pbar);
    if (holder.tvName != null && null != objBean.getName()
            && objBean.getName().trim().length() > 0) {
        holder.tvName.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getName()));
    }
    if (holder.tvId != null && null != objBean.getId()
            && objBean.getId().trim().length() > 0) {
        holder.tvId.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getId()));

    }
    if (holder.tvFlag != null && null != objBean.getFlag()
            && objBean.getFlag().trim().length() > 0) {
        holder.tvFlag.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getFlag()));

    }

    if (holder.tvimageurl != null && null != objBean.getGender()
            && objBean.getFlag().trim().length() > 0) {
        holder.tvimageurl.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getGender()));

    }

    //if (holder.tvBDate != null && null != objBean.getBirthdate()
    //      && objBean.getBirthdate().trim().length() > 0) {
    //  holder.tvBDate.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getBirthdate()));
    //}
    if (holder.tvGender != null) {
        if (null != objBean.getGender()
                && objBean.getGender().trim().length() > 0) {
            final ProgressBar pbar = holder.pbar;


            imageLoader.displayImage(objBean.getGender(), holder.tvGender,
                    options, new ImageLoadingListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingComplete() {
                            pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        }


                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingFailed() {
                            pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }


                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingStarted() {
                            pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        }
                    });

        } else {
            holder.tvGender.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon2x);
        }
    }


    return view;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvimageurl;
    public TextView tvFlag;
    public TextView tvId;
    public ProgressBar pbar;
    public TextView tvName, tvCity, tvBDate, tvAge;
    ImageView tvGender;
}


}
```

help needed.....

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827712/how-can-i-implement-adapter-for-my-list-view-to-show-iphonis-contacts-list/14473305#14473305

Comment: actually i am not looking for alphabet indexer i have other names which should be the header....

Comment: Check the given screen shot. there is customized header tooo.... given library supports the customized heders also. not only single alpha chars..

Comment: hey might be you get your answer click this [link](https://codeload.github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders/zip/master)

Answer (score 7):

I struggled quite a long time writing my own `StickyHeader` as the `StickyListHeaders` git was not perfectly matching my needs. However, the `StickyListHeaders` help me a lot in understanding how to finally have it working and therefore the writer of the `StickyListHeaders` deserve mentioning it.

Many things have to be put together to have a sticky header working.

First, declare the following

```java
private TextView mStickyHeader;
private TextView mStickyHeader2;
private int mCurrentStickyHeaderSection;
```

in `onActivityCreated`

```java
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ...     
    mCurrentStickyHeaderSection = -1;

    mStickyHeader = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textview_sticky_header_section);
    mStickyHeader2 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textview_sticky_header_section_2);

    mListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView_with_sticky_headers); 
    mListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            updateStickyHeader(firstVisibleItem);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

I assume you have written a `CustomAdapter` with section indexes and will only focus on the sticky headers.

The following method contains all that you need to have the sticky header. The tricky part is determining if the `firstVisibleItem` is a header (pos = -1) or not and the corresponding section. This part can take you a few times to have it working properly.

```java
private void updateStickyHeader(int firstVisibleItem) {
    // here is the tricky part. You have to determine pos and section
    // pos is the position within a section pos = -1 means it's the header of the section        
    // you have to determine if firstVisibleItem is a header or not
    // you also have to determine the section to which belongs the first item
    int pos = whatIsThePositionOfTheItem[firstVisibleItem];
    int section = whatIsTheSectionOfTheItem[firstVisibleItem];

    if (section != mCurrentStickyHeaderSection) {
        mStickyHeader.setText("Your_Previous_Section_Text");
        mStickyHeader2.setText("Your_Next_Section_Text");
        mCurrentStickyHeaderSection = section;
    }

    int stickyHeaderHeight = mStickyHeader.getHeight();
    if (stickyHeaderHeight == 0) {
        stickyHeaderHeight = mStickyHeader.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    View SectionLastView = mListView.getChildAt(0);
    if (SectionLastView != null && pos == -1 && SectionLastView.getBottom() <= stickyHeaderHeight) {
        int lastViewBottom = SectionLastView.getBottom();
        mStickyHeader.setTranslationY(lastViewBottom - stickyHeaderHeight);
        mStickyHeader2.setTranslationY(lastViewBottom - stickyHeaderHeight + mStickyHeader.getHeight());
    } else if (stickyHeaderHeight != 0) {
        mStickyHeader.setTranslationY(0);
        mStickyHeader2.setTranslationY(mStickyHeader.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Finally, the layout must contain a `FrameLayout` and should look like that

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    //this textview is just a global title of your listview if you need one but can be remove
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_title"
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_sticky_header_section"
            style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_sticky_header_section_2"
            style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_with_sticky_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:longClickable="true" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Update**

As asked in the comments here is an explanation of the `whatIsThePositionOfTheItem` and `whatIsTheSectionOfTheItem`. These methods have to give back the `position` and `section` of a given item.

In my case it was quite simple, my data was already containing the `section` and `position`. Actually, I am displaying text, and that text starts with the `section` and `position`. So I simply parse that text to determine the `section` and `position`.

For others, it is hard to give an example because it really depends on what you are displaying. But to make a long story short `whatIsThePositionOfTheItem` and `whatIsTheSectionOfTheItem` have to return the position and section of a given item. You will probably have to fill a table with the `position` and `section` of each item in your list and get the `position` and `section` from that table.

Comment: what do u mean by
    int pos = whatIsThePositionOfTheItem[firstVisibleItem];
    int section = whatIsTheSectionOfTheItem[firstVisibleItem];

Comment: Could i add this solution to Expandable list view?

Comment: @HpTerm This works, but when the header line count is grater than 1, the sticky header shivers on scroll. Any solution ?

Comment: @Arun I never tried with header count greater than 1. That's a good question. I have to investigate that when I find some time.

Comment: @HpTerm Great !! if u get a solution please update the answer.

Answer (score 5):

There is a library exactly with that name that implements what you want:

[image: Library demo image]

You can check it out here: https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

Comment: I am struggling with library. Can i use this library for multiple data types for different section instead of single data type?

Comment: I've never tried it. But i believe you might have to change a bit of it's code to work like that.

Comment: I am struggling with it more than 2 days, i have 3 types basically.
1- String
2- Custom class
3- Header..

Now in getview i have to check which type i am getting, i want to skip header items but i can return null view when type is header and because of that i am getting 2-3 header items.. Any help with regards to this would be really great for me..

Comment: This library has 120 issues. crap bunch of classes