# Sticky Header On RecyclerView Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have a `NavigationDrawer` which implemented by RecyclerView and a custom `RecyclerView.Adapter` , it contains of two views one for header another for list items, it works well but i want that the header view stick on the top of the list and cannot be scrolled , i don't want remove first view from `RecyclerView` and put it at the top of the `RecyclerView` view definition at parent view. is there any other way to define an offset for `RecyclerView` scroll to start at position 1(except 0)? i know how to make Sticky headers on ListView but the implementation of ListView differs from RecyclerView on onScrollListener so provided answer doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457177/how-can-i-add-a-sticky-header-to-my-listview

Comment: @Ata : i know how to make Sticky headers on ListView but the implementation of ListView differs from RecyclerView on onScrollListener so provided link doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Look here : https://github.com/eowise/recyclerview-stickyheaders